# Debian buster arm64 apt return error message, package installation works anyway

Tags: debian, apt, arm64

I'm running a debian linux on arm64 hardware, just did a dist-upgrade from stretch to buster and everything seems to be working except I'm systematically getting the following message:

`Error connecting: Could not connect: Connection refused`

After every apt command.

For example apt update will return:

```
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [121 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main arm64 Packages [7736 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-en [5968 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib arm64 Packages [38.7 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib Translation-en [44.5 kB]
Fetched 13.9 MB in 5s (3012 kB/s)
Error connecting: Could not connect: Connection refused
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Its worth noting the packages do install successfully even though the same message continue to appear, for example, installating nmap:

```
root@localhost:/home/marc# apt install nmap
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cgmanager default-mysql-server galera-3 libaio1 libass5 libavcodec57 libavdevice57 libavfilter6 libavformat57
  libavresample3 libavutil55 libbind9-140 libblas-common libbluray1 libboost-iostreams1.62.0 libcdio-cdda1
  libcdio-paranoia1 libcdio13 libcgmanager0 libconfig-inifiles-perl libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libdns162
  libdrm-freedreno1 libebur128-1 libevent-2.0-5 libfile-copy-recursive-perl libgcr-3-common libgfortran3
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main arm64 liblua5.3-0 arm64 5.3.3-1.1 [110 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main arm64 nmap-common all 7.70+dfsg1-6+deb10u1 [3898 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main arm64 nmap arm64 7.70+dfsg1-6+deb10u1 [1844 kB]
Fetched 5889 kB in 1s (11.3 MB/s)
Retrieving bug reports... Done
Parsing Found/Fixed information... Done
Selecting previously unselected package liblinear3:arm64.
(Reading database ... 88667 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../liblinear3_2.1.0+dfsg-4_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking liblinear3:arm64 (2.1.0+dfsg-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblua5.3-0:arm64.
Preparing to unpack .../liblua5.3-0_5.3.3-1.1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking liblua5.3-0:arm64 (5.3.3-1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nmap-common.
Preparing to unpack .../nmap-common_7.70+dfsg1-6+deb10u1_all.deb ...
Unpacking nmap-common (7.70+dfsg1-6+deb10u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nmap.
Preparing to unpack .../nmap_7.70+dfsg1-6+deb10u1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking nmap (7.70+dfsg1-6+deb10u1) ...
Setting up nmap-common (7.70+dfsg1-6+deb10u1) ...
Setting up liblinear3:arm64 (2.1.0+dfsg-4) ...
Setting up liblua5.3-0:arm64 (5.3.3-1.1) ...
Setting up nmap (7.70+dfsg1-6+deb10u1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
Error connecting: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from one of your system’s `apt` hooks, which aren’t essential to the system’s overall functionality. You’ll find details in the files under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`; I suspect the culprit in your case could be PackageKit (`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20packagekit`).

If you want to figure out which one is failing, rename each file in turn, adding `.disabled` to its name, and run `apt update` again. Rename each file back afterwards, until you find the failing hook.

Comment: Wonderfull, it was indeed 20packagekit who messed everything up. What is the impact of disabling it ? Should I fix it or can my system work without it safely ?

Comment: The technical impact is that PackageKit won’t be aware of what `apt` is doing; the only user-visible impact of that is that, if you have a desktop environment running on your ARM64 system, and that environment relies on PackageKit for software upgrades, you won’t get notified about them. If you use `apt` for your package management it won’t make any material difference.