# How to fix broken apt-get in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, python, python3

I think I may have broken something with python because I previously tried to update to python3, linked it to /usr/bin/python (which I now realize is the wrong thing to do) don't have the commands specifically that were used.

I can no longer get apt-get update or any apt-get commands to work on my system.

Here is the result of an apt-get update:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli bionic InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:7 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com bionic InRelease
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

I also was able to presumably fix my pythonpath:

```
~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install python
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python is already the newest version (2.7.15~rc1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 182 not upgraded.
```

Now my python links look like this:

```
~$ ls -al /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Apr  1 10:30 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python2.7
```

and python3 is no longer linked to /usr/bin/python:

```
~$ ls -al /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Mar  1 21:22 /usr/bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.8
```

Made some slight progress here by using update-alternatives:

```
update-alternatives --list python
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python3.8


sudo update-alternatives --config python
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.8   2         auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/python2.7   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.8   2         manual mode
```

Whether I leave it at python3.8 or switch to the python2.7 (with update-alternatives --config python) I keep getting the same output from apt-get

Does anyone have any theories on how to fix this? It is still pointing to python3 despite setting the python alternatives to 2.7. I presume there is a problem with update-conf-db somehow.

Comment: please add `apt-cache policy python3` to your question.

Answer (score 4):

The errors you’re getting aren’t caused by `apt` directly, but by one of its hooks; specifically, the updates for `command-not-found` (the helper which tells you which package to install when you try to run a command which doesn’t exist on your system). `apt update` itself has completed successfully.

To avoid the errors, disable the hook:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50command-not-found{,.disabled}
```

You should then be able to run `apt update` without seeing errors. If another hook fails, you can disable that using the same technique as above (see also [Debian buster arm64 apt return error message, package installation works anyway](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/618308/86440)).

`update-cnf-db` is a Python 3 script, so your Python 3 setup might be broken as well. Determining how to fix that in your situation would require more information; you should make sure that your `/usr/bin/python3` points to Ubuntu’s version of Python 3.

Once you’ve got `update-cnf-db` working, you can re-enable the hook by reversing the command above:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50command-not-found{.disabled,}
```

Comment: This seems more in line with what my problem might be; thank you for answering. What is "Ubuntu's version of python 3?" It points to an installed version presently which is probably not what I want?

Comment: I mean the version provided by the Ubuntu packages; it’s just a hunch, but the “ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'” error means that whatever `/usr/bin/python3` is, it can’t find the appropriate `apt_pkg` module, and that’s version-dependent — *e.g.* on my system with `python3.9`, it’s `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. If `python3` points to another version of Python, there won’t be a corresponding `apt_pkg` module.

Comment: It could also be that `python3-apt` is broken, but that would be a little more surprising.

Comment: Interesting; Thank you it looks like /usr/lib/python3/dist-package directory is missing the apt_pkg module so that might confirm a broken python3 - trying to fix that now, presumably one of the python3 versions would be the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

The same error occurred in ubuntu 18.04.

after execute `sudo apt update` occurred error like this:

```
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

OS environment is

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

I tried to :

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
ls -la /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

It's all OK.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Does "It's all OK" mean (1) those commands ran successfully but you still have the overall problem, or (2) after running those commands, the problem is resolved?